# C Error: called object is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c

I'm writing a text-based adventure game to improve at coding, and I'm writing it in C since that's what I'm using at school. I keep getting the error game.c:28:15: error: called object 'room2' is not a function or function pointer. Any tips for how I can improve my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int c;
void start(), begin(), room2();

int main(){
   start();
   return 0;
}

void start(){
   printf("Welcome to the Adventure Game! Press s to start\n");
   c = getchar();
   if(c=='s'){begin();}
}

void begin(){
   printf("Text here involving describing a room and directions the player can take, if they press n they will go north\n");
   c = getchar();
   if(c=='n'){room2();}/*This is where I get the error*/
}

void room2(){
   printf("Describes room2 and the player's surroundings, etc\n");
}
```

Comment: [There is no error](https://ideone.com/Ix8zSI).

Comment: Which compiler you are using ? Tell us the exact version of compiler.

Comment: I'm using gcc with a linux vm

Comment: @SlowCuber17: which version of gcc ?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure

Comment: type gcc --version on your terminal to know the version of gcc

Comment: You are overwriting somewhere. E.g Like `void start(), begin(), room2;`

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) 6.3.0 20170406

Comment: @SlowCuber17: I am unable to reproduce this error. Please provide minimal, complete & verifiable example show that we can help you

Comment: So I rewrote the code the same way I have it above in a new gedit file, and that compiled fine. It didn't display any text, but at least it didn't return any errors. But when I went back to my original file, after cutting it down to the exact same code, then after saving and compiling it still gave the same error I've been getting. The code is exactly the same as the other file, but one gives an error and one doesn't.

Comment: @SlowCuber17 diff file1 file2 will show you lines that differ between file1 and file2.

Answer (score 0):

try to move the difinition of each function to be above the line where it is called like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int c;
void start(), begin(), room2();

void room2(){
   printf("Describes room2 and the player's surroundings, etc\n");
}

void begin(){
   printf("Text here involving describing a room and directions the player can take, if they press n they will go north\n");
   c = getchar();
   if(c=='n'){room2();}/*This is where I get the error*/
}

void start(){
   printf("Welcome to the Adventure Game! Press s to start\n");
   c = getchar();
   if(c=='s'){begin();}
}

int main(){
   start();
   return 0;
}
```

still have a problem change c into char

Comment: Now I'm getting the error: 'room2' redeclared as different kind of symbol 
    void room2(){

Comment: remove the difinition line of the three functions....there is another thing but I think it is not important...remove the number 2 from room2 @SlowCuber17